# Error: vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Sorry. I don't understand, why Vue executes code v-for and broken with another

```
<div v_model="main">
    <tr v-for="item in main" >
        <th scope="row">[[ item.name ]]</th>
    </tr>
</div>
```

dosn't wort

```
<div v_model="main">
    <tr v-for="item in main" >
        <th scope="row">[[ item.name ]]</th>
    </tr>
</div>
```

working code:

```
<li class="form-control input-xs" v-for="item in main">
    <label> [[ item.name ]] </label>
</li>
```

I used Django, because option: delimiters: ['[[', ']]']

Help me, please understand this error.

Comment: replace [[ item.name ]] with {{ item.name }} also v_model is actually v-model. Have a read of the vue documentation and follow along slowly. You do not need that v-model="main" anyway for the loop to work

Comment: Sorry, It is need for Django with delimiters: ['[[', ']]'], I forgot say about it

Comment: Yes, I agree with you about v-model. I don't understand because one case work, another not. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Did @Spangle's comment answer your question or do you still have the same warning showing?

Comment: @Phil, No, I still get warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to your invalid HTML.

Vue is validating your document structure and since `<tr>` should only ever be a child of `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>` (see [`<tr>`: The Table Row element - Technical summary - Permitted parents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#Technical_summary)), your `v-for` expression is not evaluated.

Here's a working example...

```js
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    main: [
      { name: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { name: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { name: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { name: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table border="1">
    <tr v-for="item in main" >
      <th scope="row">[[ item.name ]]</th>
      <td>[[ item.done ? '✔️' : '❌' ]]</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```